# How to start a video playing from nav menu link?

Tags: html, video, youtube

Would like to link to the video library page (testimonials .html) and trigger start play of a certain video in the library.

There are 12 videos in the library - using #named anchor only goes to the page not the specific video I have tagged. Then have to click the play button. Can this be set to trigger play from the nav link?

Here is example of a video in the testimonials.html page:

```
<!-- video seven -->
    <div class="box three">
    <!-- portfolio title-->
    <h6><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BtsQ35VukQ" title="Hearing Healthcare for Parents &amp; Children">Hearing Healthcare<br />
    for Parents &amp; Children</a></h6>
    <!-- portfolio image for images -->
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BtsQ35VukQ" title="Hearing Healthcare for Parents &amp; Children" rel="prettyPhoto[portfolio]" class="imgeffect play"><iframe width="320" height="240" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CWPV5sJQMRk?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe> </a>
    <p>
    <!-- text-->
    Hearing Healthcare for Parents &amp; Children <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BtsQ35VukQ" title="Patients Recommend Dr. Martinetti">read more</a>
    </p>
    </div>
    <!-- end/video seven -->
```